# lambda function callback returns error : C++ no suitable conversion function from to exists

Tags: c++11, lambda

i try to implement simple lambda callback to open source function like this :

i want to pass to the lambda the :  GLFWwindow* window;
which is defined in the header of GLFWManager

```
void GLFWManager::handleExitGame()
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, [this](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)->GLFWkeyfun {

        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {

        }

    });
}
```

the signetures are :

```
GLFWAPI GLFWkeyfun glfwSetKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, GLFWkeyfun callback);
typedef void (* GLFWkeyfun)(GLFWwindow*,int,int,int,int);
```

i keep getting this compiler error :

```
C++ no suitable conversion function from to exists
```

Comment: GLFW is a C library, it doesn't know anything about C++ classes and objects, or lambdas. Only capture-less lambdas can be implicitly converted to a function pointers as expected by the `glfwSetKeyCallback` function. Furthermore, you declare that the lambda should return a value of the type `GLFWkeyfun` when it should return `void`. Please read more about [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: can't it just be as anonymous function as in the end its just pointer to function

Comment: mybe how can i wrap it to be lambda ?